# How to conditionally %include a *.sas file that defines a macro?

Tags: sas, include, sas-macro

I use a macro in several SAS programs, so I defined it in a separate file `/myFolder/myMacro.sas`.

When running in batch, I want to use it this way: `%include '/myFolder/myMacro.sas;'`

When testing changes to the code in Enterprise Guide, I wan to edit and run `/myFolder/myMacro.sas`, then edit and run the programs that use it. How do I conditionally include the macro definitions?

`%if &server = BATCH_SERVER %then %include '/myFolder/myMacro.sas;'` does not work: The file is included anyway and the `%if` statement is applied to the comment on top of the file and results in

```
ERROR: Expected %DO not found.
ERROR: Skipping to next %END statement.
```

Comment: So you only want the %include to run when you are running in batch mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the error occurs because the include file starts with comments, somthing like:

```
* MyMacro is written to do this and that *;
* ************************************** *;
%macro MyMacro;
    proc this;
    proc that;
    run;
%mend;
```

So after including the file, this becomes

```
%if &server = BATCH_SERVER %then * MyMacro is written to do this and that *;
* ************************************** *;
%macro MyMacro;
    proc this;
    proc that;
    run;
%mend;
```

which is invalid.

## When working inside a macro: add `%do;` and `%end;`

As Allan suggested, it is sufficient to put the `%inlcude` between `%do;` and `%end;`

```
%if &server = BATCH_SERVER %then %do;
    %include '/myFolder/myMacro.sas;'
%end;
```

So after including the file, this becomes

```
%if &server = BATCH_SERVER %then %do;
    * MyMacro is written to do this and that *;
    * ************************************** *;
    %macro MyMacro;
        proc this;
        proc that;
        run;
    %mend;
%end;
```

which works.

## When working in open code: use `call execute`

```
data _null_;
    if "&mode"="BATCH" then call execute ("%include /myFolder/myMacro.sas;");
run;
%DoIt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `%then %do`

```
%let mode=BATCH;
filename mac1 temp;
filename mac2 temp;

data _null_;
  file mac1;
  put '%macro mac1;%put mac1;%mend;%mac1;';
data _null_;
  file mac2;
  put '%macro mac2;%put mac2;%mend;%mac2';
run;
%if &mode=BATCH %then %do;
  %inc mac2;
%end;
%else %do;
  %inc mac1;
%end;
```

Comment: Right, Allan, that is the sollution, but your answer deviated so much from the question I cannot accept it a THE answer to the question.